# PIL images are saving in grayscale

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to generate some fractal images and I can do it fine. However, I have some problems when saving the images, because it saves them in grayscale instead of the colours. When I open them in python, it shows the right colours.

The code is as follows

```
from PIL import Image
import ImageDraw
from scipy import misc
from array import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy

image = Image.new("L",(SIZE, SIZE)) # create a image SIZE x SIZE
d = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
#iterate over x and y, setting a col value for each pixel
d.point((x, y), col ) # it then colors the point (x,y)
image.save("beta"+str(alpha)+".png", "PNG")
```

I'm using macOS X, Python 2.7.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating images in `L`, or Luminance mode. That means they are greyscale images, one band of colour.

You need to use the `RGB` mode instead:

```
image = Image.new("RGB", (SIZE, SIZE))
```

This does require you to use tuples of `(R, G, B)` values when specifying pixels, not a simple integer. The `ImageDraw` module does support setting colours using strings as well (`'#rrggbb'` and related).

You don't show us how you define `col` in your code, so it is hard to state if you are using the correct format for an RGB image.

Comment: Well, I was adapting a code, but to update the col values, I was just setting it to a different integer value. I will look into using RGB. How exactly should I define col then? Just a tuple of (value,value,value)?

Comment: @DanielAbramovici: A tuple will do, yes. See the [ImageDraw documentation](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagedraw.htm) for other supported values.

Comment: You can actually also use an integer. I asked exactly that question (using integer for colored image) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192671/pil-image-mode-i-is-grayscale/32200857