# PIL Image mode I is grayscale?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to specify the colours of my image in Integer format instead of (R,G,B) format. I assumed that I had to create an image in mode "I" since according to the [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#modes):

> The mode of an image defines the type and depth of a pixel in the
> image. The current release supports the following standard modes:
>
> - 1 (1-bit pixels, black and white, stored with one pixel per byte)
> - L (8-bit pixels, black and white)
> - P (8-bit pixels, mapped to any other mode using a colour palette)
> - RGB (3x8-bit pixels, true colour)
> - RGBA (4x8-bit pixels, true colour with transparency mask)
> - CMYK (4x8-bit pixels, colour separation)
> - YCbCr (3x8-bit pixels, colour video format)
> - **I (32-bit signed integer pixels)**
> - F (32-bit floating point pixels)

However this seems to be a grayscale image. Is this expected? Is there a way of specifying a coloured image based on a 32-bit integer? In my MWE I even let PIL decide how to convert "red" to the "I" format.

---

#### MWE

```
from PIL import Image

ImgRGB=Image.new('RGB', (200,200),"red") # create a new blank image
ImgI=Image.new('I', (200,200),"red") # create a new blank image
ImgRGB.show()
ImgI.show()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there a way of specifying a coloured image based on a 32-bit integer?

Yes, use the RGB format for that, but instead use an integer instead of "red" as the color argument:

```
from PIL import Image

r, g, b = 255, 240, 227
intcolor = (b << 16 ) | (g << 8 ) | r                                       
print intcolor # 14938367
ImgRGB = Image.new("RGB", (200, 200), intcolor)
ImgRGB.show()
```

Comment: Works perfectly! An additional question, that integer format is different than what I'm used to, I'm used to the byte ordering being R G B. Is this a particularity of PIL or is it a more complex issue?

Comment: @Miguel Pillow uses R,G,B by preference too. Usually you'd use this when you have RGB values: `Image.new("RGB", (200, 200), (255, 240, 227))` which is basically ``Image.new("RGB", (200, 200), (r, g, b))``

Comment: What I meant is that I'm used to see `intcol=R<<16 | G<<8 | B` and not `intcol=B<<16 | G<<8 | R`

Comment: I thought pillow used that too, so that was what I tried at first. However, it seems that on a low level Pillow uses a BGR packing. Pillow is not unique in that, I've seen that in other graphics packages also. Perhaps it's a kind of preference or legacy the original developers had to work with. Who knows?

Comment: On little endian system (most of us have those) "B<<16 | G<<8 | R" is RGB since the value for R takes the byte with the lower address.